# Conexión MySQL en Flutter usando el paquete mysql1

Tags: mysql, flutter, mysql-workbench, dart, conexión

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos MySQL usando el paquete mysql1 para Flutter. La conexión parece que la hago bien, pero al ejecutar la query, ésta no devuelve nada.

Dejo capturas del código y base de datos por si sabéis a qué se debe. También dejo el video que he seguido por si no se copiar y veis la errata... Muchas gracias.

**mysql.dart**

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Mysql {
  static String host = '10.0.2.2',
                user = 'root',
                password = '6300',
                db = 'company';
  static int port = 3306;

  Mysql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async{
    var settings = ConnectionSettings(
      host: host,
      port: port,
      user: user,
      password: password,
      db: db
    );
    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
  var db =  Mysql();
  var mail = '';

  void _getData() {
    db.getConnection().then((conn) {
      String sql = 'select mail from customer where id = 1';
      conn.query(sql).then((results) {
        print(results.length);
        for(var row in results) {
          setState(() {
            mail = row[0];
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**Resultado de la búsqueda en MySQLWorkbench**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado de la ejecución de la app**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Videotutorial**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ig6WRq73iEg&ab_channel=Flutter

Comment: Si debugueas después la resolución de tu conexión, para ver si entra en ese punto, ` db.getConnection().then()`, por que creo el problema es que intentas conectarte a localhost pero de tu maquina

Comment: La base de datos a la que quiero acceder está en mi máquina. Flutter reconoce el host 10.0.2.2 como localhost (localhost  y 127.0.0.1 no funcionan).

Necesito conectarme a una base de datos externa en otra máquina y estoy probando este paquete porque parece ser bastante famoso. Si conoces alguna forma óptima de hacer esto mismo estoy abierto a propuestas.

Comment: @StyleMain ¿probaste usando la IP de red de la máquina?